# Iterate Collection and Assign Each to Single Property with OR Operator

Tags: c#

For example, this `SecurityProtocol` property can be assigned using an `OR` operator:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Now if we wanted to not hard code this assignment in the application by moving it to AppSettings as a comma-separated string like `"192,768,3072"`, how would we convert the string to it's enumeration and assign it to a property using an `OR` operator?

Comment: You can cast an integer to an enum value: `var x = (SecurityProtocolType)192;`. Further more, you can `|` integers together, you can split strings on commas, and you can parse integers with `Int32.Parse()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Flags]
public enum E
{
    Foo = 1 << 2,
    Bar = 1 << 4,
    Baz = 1 << 9,

    Planxty = Foo | Bar | Baz
}
```

...

```
var s = "16,4,512";

E enumresult = 
    //  Split string by commas...
    s.Split(',')
    //  Parse each numeric substring in turn and cast the result to the enum type...
    .Select(nstr => (E)Int32.Parse(nstr))
    //  bitwise or each succeeding value against the rest
    .Aggregate((a, b) => a | b);
```

You can cast an integer directly to an enum value, provided it's a valid value for that enum type. This will work fine:

```
var x = (E)(4 | 512);
```

Comment: I might cast in `Select` or possibly `Aggregate<T>` to just return the right type: `("192,768,3072").Split(',').Select(x => (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)int.Parse(x)).Aggregate((x,y) => x | y)`

Comment: Thank you. This is my first experience with bit operations on enums.

Answer (score 0):

You can split it by commas and apply `|` in a loop to parsed value array you have got from split:

```
string v = "192,768,3072";
string[] vals = v.Split(',');
var result = (SecurityProtocolType)int.Parse(vals[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < vals.Length; i++) 
    result = result | (SecurityProtocolType)int.Parse(vals[i]);
```

Here is the **[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMv643)**

You can create a function for it like"

```
public static SecurityProtocolType GetProtocolType(string v)
{
     string[] vals = v.Split(',');
     var result = (SecurityProtocolType)int.Parse(vals[0]);
     for (int i = 1; i < vals.Length; i++) 
     result = result | (SecurityProtocolType)int.Parse(vals[i]);
     return result;
}
```

and use it like:

```
GetProtocolType("192,3072");
```

**[DEMO](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z28w4d)**